# Synchronizing a paper.js canvas with a 'regular' canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

What I'm already doing:

- I have a [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org) canvas working just fine
- Just below it (same position, same size), I have another
  canvas(regular one, no paper.js binded to this one).
- On regular intervals, *I copy the contents* of the paper.js canvas to
  the regular canvas by using the canvas native `drawImage()` command

---

My question is this:

**How can I synchronise the 2 in terms of zooming/panning?**

I want to be able to *scroll & zoom* the `View` and the canvas below to do the same so that when I copy the paper.js canvas to the regular canvas the items appear identical(also items that are already there should be zoomed/panned together with the paper.js canvas)

I have tried `canvas.scale(2,2)` on the canvas below and `view.zoom = 2;` on my Paper.js canvas but the 2 don't play well together in terms of having the same positions/translations and zooming. I am aware that the drawing already placed would be pixelated when zooming on the second canvas - but I don't really mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the matrix object and apply it to your regular canvas. I am not familiar with paper.js but you should be able to do something like this:

```
// aLayer by reference or via project.activeLayer
aLayer.matrix.applyToContext(yourOtherContextHere);
```

See these for details:

- [activeLayer](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#activelayer)
- [layer](http://paperjs.org/reference/layer/)
- [layer.matrix](http://paperjs.org/reference/layer/#matrix)
- [matrix](http://paperjs.org/reference/matrix/)

Comment: Hm, sounds promising - I'll give it a try and come back soon. Thanks